# Doctrine : how to manipulate a collection?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

With symfony && doctrine 1.2 in an action, i try to display the top ranked website for a user.

I did :

```
 public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->user = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->websites = $this->user->Websites; 
  }
```

The only problem is that it returns a Doctrine collection with all the websites in it and not only the Top ranked ones.

I already setup a method (`getTopRanked()`) but if I do :

```
$this->user->Websites->getTopRanked()
```

It fails.

If anyone has an idea to alter the Doctrine collection to filter only the top ranked.

Thanks

PS: my method looks like (in websiteTable.class.php) :

```
   public function getTopRanked()
{
  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('Website')
      ->orderBy('nb_votes DESC')
       ->limit(5);
  return $q->execute();

}
```

Comment: Where did you put `getTopRanked()` and how does it look like?

Comment: See my edit, i've added the function. :-)

Comment: You are reading the values for all websites, not all websites that belong to a certain user. ALtough you call it from within a user object your query doesn't use a user value... I don't think Doctrine will add the required JOINs on its own.

Comment: the $this->user->x() methods are the ones in your user model. you placed this function in your websiteTable model, which is entirely different.

You should either create a function in the website model that takes in a userid (eg toprankedbyuser($user) ) or, if you want to access it like you do above, create a function in the user model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather pass Doctrine_Query between methods:

```
//action
public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)   
{
   $this->user = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
   $this->websites = $this->getUser()->getWebsites(true);  
}

//user
  public function getWebsites($top_ranked = false)
  {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->from('Website w')
     ->where('w.user_id = ?', $this->getId());
    if ($top_ranked)
    {
      $q = Doctrine::getTable('Website')->addTopRankedQuery($q);
    }
    return $q->execute();
  }

//WebsiteTable
public function addTopRankedQuery(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
  $alias = $q->getRootAlias();
  $q->orderBy($alias'.nb_votes DESC')
    ->limit(5)
  return $q
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was possible to alter a doctrine collection.

Answer (score 1):

If getTopRanked() is a method in your user model, then you would access it with `$this->user->getTopRanked()`

Comment: Well i need to retrieve the website for a user with the alias "Websites" before filtering it no ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case $this->user->Websites contains ALL user websites. As far as I know there's no way to filter existing doctrine collection (unless you will iterate through it and choose interesting elements).

I'd simply implement getTopRankedWebsites() method in the User class:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
  public function getTopRankedWebsites()
  {
    WebsiteTable::getTopRankedByUserId($this->getId());
  }
}
```

And add appropriate query in the WebsiteTable:

```
class WebsiteTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function getTopRankedByUserId($userId)
  {
    return Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->from('Website w')
     ->where('w.user_id = ?', array($userId))
     ->orderBy('w.nb_votes DESC')
     ->limit(5)
     ->execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `getFirst()` function

```
$this->user->Websites->getTopRanked()->getFirst()
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_collection.html#getFirst()